# How to fix the error '404 Not Found The resource requested could not be found on this server'

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

I designed the website  danielperez.org which I'm hosting on an EC2 instance with  WordPress and Open Litespeed technologies. I have everything connected on Route 53. I have issued an SSL using Amazon Certificate Manager and attached it to a Load Balancer. The site was working fine and suddenly just out of nowhere is showing this message "404 Not Found. The resource requested could not be found on this server!" I'm sure I might not be following the best practices on the AWS console, or this just happens... so I would appreciate it if somebody would help me solve this somehow.

Comment: It does not work from your domain only, or it does not work at all? What if you ssh to your instance? Can you curl if from inside?

Comment: OK, So after I ssh to my instance what should I do?

Comment: I am using a pre configured Amazon Machine Image called ´WordPress with LiteSpeed Cache (Powered OpenLiteSpeed´. https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/LiteSpeed-Technologies-Inc-WordPress-with-LiteSpee/B07KSC2QQN

The database is included there, with Wordpress: 

Main Components:

OpenLiteSpeed
LiteSpeed Cache
WordPress
phpMyAdmin
LSPHP


any thoughts on what should I do in this case? 

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you confirm if it works if there's no AWS Load Balancer involved?